# How to modify the NDIS driver for allowed multiple handle to bind to a specific interface?

Tags: driver, communication, ethernet, ndis

I am trying to perform a simultaneous read and write with the NDIS driver synchronously, using 2 threads.
In [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608321/windows-ndis-driver-concurrent-read-write-on-a-single-device-irp-mj-read-write), @falstaff comments: "Thanks, the trick with the two handles works. Initially, this didn't work since the driver only allowed one handle to bind to a specific interface. But I had to alter the driver to allow multiple clients to be connected anyway. So now every client connects twice, once for read and once for write..."

I would like to know what modification is needed in the driver, as I can't manage to identify it.

Thank you very much in advance, any help.
Best regards.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure myself, but at a minimum, I can see that the sample's handling of `OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER` assumes only 1 handle at a time. If you open 2 handles then close 1 handle, the packet filter will be incorrectly cleared. It should instead keep the packet filter until there are 0 total outstanding handles.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @jeffrey Tippet. The truth is that I have so many doubts on this issue, that I am not even clear on the direction to keep testing. I need to clarify how it all works to have a correct basis.

To try to modify the driver to accept two simultaneous connections in separate threads, I was focusing on the CreateFileA and DeviceIoControl functions.

Assuming the driver accepts two simultaneous clients, the structure would be to open two threads, and in each thread run CreateFileA and DevceIoControl, to write to one and read from the other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I continue to progress and right now I am not having any problem opening the two handles, in independent threads, with CreateFileA. However, I have the following doubt: Is it possible to call the DevceIoControl function, in different threads, with the same pointer to the network card identifier? If it is possible, how would it be done? It returns error in all the tests performed. Thank you very much.