# Windows socket write() is blocked by a read() unexpectedly

Tags: windows, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, winsock

(this is an updated repost of a previously [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326596/windows-socket-seems-to-be-non-duplex) question, posted with old account which I've lost the credentials for)

I'm writing a client-server program, where the client is C++/winapi and the server is C#/.net.

socket is an AF_INET/ SOCK_STREAM and I'm using Readfile() and WriteFile() for socket IO at client.

the client have a loop where it reads from server (and may block the calling thread [denote t1] , which is fine with me). it also have another thread [denote t2] , that wait on an Event object with a timeout.

if the timeout is reached (and the Event is yet to be singled) the t2 thread, will write (exacly on byte) on the same socket.

The problem I have, is that it seems like the write won't return untill the read on t1 returns (in some legitimate scnerions it will never happen) , as if the socket was not full-duplex.

I've checked it buttom to top, there are no other thread-related comlications. I acctually ran the client from a diffrent machine, and used wireshark to sniff traffic. After the timeout was reached, there was nothing on the wire (no matter how long I wait) , untill I wrote some data from server side (so the read() on t1 returned) - and just right after that, the write() of client is finally transmitted.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/16708230/886887 might be applicable.  Perhaps you need to duplicate the socket handle, or use asynchronous I/O?

Comment: Sockets use overlapped I/O internally by default.

Comment: You can merge your accounts, see the [help page on merging users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in your earlier question, sockets **are** full duplex.  A read in one thread will not block a write in another thread, and vice versa.